# What user should I create and execute cron jobs as? Apache? Root? Me?

Tags: linux, centos, cron, users

I'm setting up a new Webserver and having trouble getting cron to execute as expected. I am using a script to create cron jobs in `.tmp/crontab.txt`, which is then moved to `/var/spool/cron` under the user "Apache". These Apache entries don't execute as far as I can tell.

`/var/spool/cron`: has 3 user files:

- Root  0 bytes
- Apache 344 bytes (looks good, does not execute).
- JLee 3514 bytes(this is where all my manual entries went).

The manual jobs I schedule are being executed normally. However, the manual jobs create a "sub-cron" and that is the one going to Apache. What am I doing wrong?

I would prefer all cron jobs be created under one User, as I am the admin and sole user of this server.

Comment: It seems like you have multiple questions? 1. Why is the crontab of `apache` not executed? 2. Which UID should be used to run cron jobs as? -- To the first one: do not edit crontabs directly, use `crontab`. These files are not ment to be changed manually (at least for some implementations of `cron`). To the second one: running all jobs as one user is likely a security risk, as only root can do *everything* technically possible. If you explain your intentions (what should the server do? Is it accessible from the internet?) you might get better answers.

Comment: Yes I use schedule tasks in Plesk to enter cron. That is what I mean by manual. Schedule tasks runs fine. The cron job execute a php script which then, attempts to create the sub-cron, which fails.

Answer (score 2):

The cron daemon doesn't read the new files if you just copy them. You should use the crontab command to install the new crontab file. It also signals the cron daemon to read the files.

From the crontab man page:

```
...and though these are files in /var, they are not  intended  to  be
   edited directly.
```

Comment: Hi Keith, yes I am trying to avoid editing them directly. So I'm placing crontab.txt in /tmp and the system has assigned that file to "apache". Can I change that "apache" to a different user when writing this file?  Thank you.

Comment: Is the script running as root?

Comment: I should also mention the "apache user" is not authorized to run cron, therefore the jobs just sit there. Yes I run a single script as root.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been pointed out in the [answer from Keith](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230199/100397), you should not put files directly into `/var/spool/cron` as they will not be seen by `crond`.

You should maintain your own instance of a user's `crontab` file, and use the `crontab` command to signal the changes to `crond`:

```
echo '* * * * * date >>/tmp/output' | crontab
```

If you can create multiple entries you could write each one to its own file and then `cat` the results into a single `crontab`.

```
mkdir .crondir
...
echo '* * * * * echo job1 >> /tmp/output.1' > .crondir/job1
echo '* * * * * echo job2 >> /tmp/output.2' > .crondir/job2
echo '* * * * * echo job3 >> /tmp/output.3' > .crondir/job3
cat .crondir/job* | crontab
```

Obviously it's necessary that the user running the `crontab` command has rights to use it. Depending on how you have set up your permissions scheme for your application it could be its own user account. Otherwise it might have to be your web server user (`apache`) or possibly even `root`.